# C++ struct was not declared this scope

Tags: c++, struct

Using struct like linked list creates problem.
When I declare 2 values (my struct),
it returns error:

> this VALUE_NAME was not declared this scope

This is part of the source.

```
struct _node
{
    int val;
    _node* prev;
    _node* next;
};
typedef struct _node node;

node* HEAD;

void deleteALLNode()
{
    node* node = HEAD;
    node* _tmp;

//
// here _tmp value return error
//
}
```

Comment: where is `VALUE_NAME`?

Comment: `node` is `typedef struct _node`. It is also a *pointer* to the same `struct`?

Comment: VALUE_NAME is  _tmp.  sorry

Comment: node is struct _node. node* is _node*

Comment: ^ `node*` is a type, not a variable!

Comment: Please tag with either `c` or `c++`

Comment: C or C++, a type/tag name with a leading underscore is best avoided

Comment: Why is node* available elsewhere? : node* node = HEAD

Comment: Why don't you want to provide minimal example that reproduces your error?

Comment: I fixed it. Point is node* "node" and struct node. same name value & struct. Thanks all!!

Comment: C and C++ are different languages with different rules and the answers are going to be different. Pick one language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot name your variable with same name, as type (you can one time maybe, but than you cannot use the type without compilation error anymore). Just change name of `node* node = HEAD;` variable to something else, like `node* pNode = HEAD;`

Comment: Thanks! I fixed it like your way.

Comment: If you have fixed it by yourself, please add own answer to your question and accept it, so anybody with same problem can find solution quickly :-)

Answer (score -2):

If it's C++, you can use `_node` directly, no need to `typedef`. `typedef` a struct is C style.

```
struct _node
{
    int val;
    _node* prev;
    _node* next;
};

_node* HEAD;

void deleteALLNode()
{
    _node* node = HEAD;
    _node* _tmp;
}
```

Comment: it return same error. _tmp was not declared in this scope.

Comment: It passed on GCC 4.9.2. Which compiler are you using?

Comment: oh! yes i use gcc 447